# ST_intersects returns different result for Geometry params vs Geography params

Tags: postgis, geography-data-type, geometry-data-type

`ST_Intersects` returns `true` for geography parameters but it returns false for geometry params:

Following is the query for `geometry` params and it returns `true` which is incorrect.

```
select ST_Intersects (st_geomFromGeoJson('{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-32.874625683,-14.310263903],[-32.874625683,73.854441883],[177.939840317,73.854441883],[177.939840317,-14.310263903],[-32.874625683,-14.310263903]]]}')::geography, st_geomFromGeoJson('{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-93.5582962,30.8692111],[-93.5599975,30.8647117],[-93.5613937,30.8619117],[-93.5619964,30.8588123],[-93.5597,30.8556118],[-93.5576934,30.8534126],[-93.5634002,30.8473129],[-93.565895,30.8462123],[-93.5680999,30.8446121],[-93.564598,30.8421115],[-93.5589981,30.8405132],[-93.5558929,30.8377113],[-93.5537948,30.8350124],[-93.553894,30.831911],[-93.5557937,30.830511],[-93.5570983,30.8282127],[-93.5543975,30.8247127],[-93.5572967,30.8219127],[-93.5610961,30.8198127],[-93.5639953,30.8175125],[-93.5637969,30.8136119],[-93.5614929,30.8108119],[-93.5613937,30.8082122],[-93.5631942,30.8062133],[-93.5657958,30.804512],[-93.5692977,30.8030128],[-93.5735931,30.8021125],[-93.5783996,30.8020133],[-93.581398,30.803112],[-93.583496,30.8015117],[-93.5841979,30.7979125],[-93.5833969,30.794012],[-93.5815963,30.7907123],[-93.5837936,30.7882118],[-93.5868988,30.7879123],[-93.5891952,30.7871112],[-93.5884933,30.7850131],[-93.5870971,30.7831134],[-93.5839004,30.7795124],[-93.5876998,30.7778129],[-93.5914001,30.7766113],[-93.5930938,30.7710132],[-93.591896,30.7657127],[-93.5951004,30.7630119],[-93.5979995,30.7627124],[-93.6012954,30.7614116],[-93.6041946,30.7606124],[-93.6057968,30.7642116],[-93.6064987,30.7618122],[-93.606697,30.7588119],[-93.6100997,30.757513],[-93.6113967,30.7594127],[-93.6130981,30.7606124],[-93.6144943,30.7589111],[-93.6145935,30.7559127],[-93.612297,30.7538127],[-93.6092987,30.7491111],[-93.6084976,30.7470111],[-93.6099929,30.7452125],[-93.6145935,30.7444133],[-93.6177978,30.7432117],[-93.6189956,30.7409114],[-93.6167984,30.7381114],[-93.6133956,30.7369117],[-93.6114959,30.7347126],[-93.6095962,30.7306118],[-93.6114959,30.728012],[-93.6093978,30.7241115],[-93.612297,30.7221107],[-93.609497,30.7187118],[-93.6130981,30.7171115],[-93.6147003,30.7194118],[-93.6167984,30.7183113],[-93.6162948,30.7147121],[-93.6167984,30.712511],[-93.6189956,30.7098121],[-93.6210937,30.7040119],[-93.6241989,30.7009124],[-93.6237945,30.6980113],[-93.6211929,30.6959114],[-93.6226959,30.6927127],[-93.6251983,30.6899108],[-93.6271972,30.6871128],[-93.6277999,30.684412],[-93.6306991,30.6789131],[-93.6347961,30.676712],[-93.6369934,30.6745128],[-93.6388931,30.6730117],[-93.6443939,30.6735134],[-93.6464004,30.6712112],[-93.647499,30.6686115],[-93.6514968,30.6699123],[-93.6541976,30.670412],[-93.6559982,30.6687126],[-93.6582946,30.664112],[-93.6604995,30.6618118],[-93.6646957,30.6618118],[-93.6681976,30.6601123],[-93.670494,30.6572132],[-93.6702957,30.653511],[-93.6735992,30.6505126],[-93.6756973,30.6470127],[-93.6780929,30.6446132],[-93.6822967,30.6414127],[-93.6808929,30.6359119],[-93.6833953,30.6324119],[-93.6838989,30.6296119],[-93.6848983,30.6265125],[-93.6819992,30.6200122],[-93.6854934,30.6164112],[-93.6870956,30.613512],[-93.6893997,30.6118125],[-93.6877975,30.6101131],[-93.6842956,30.6089115],[-93.6828994,30.6066112],[-93.6824951,30.6042118],[-93.6791,30.5995121],[-93.6791,30.5937118],[-93.6837997,30.5931129],[-93.6850967,30.5905113],[-93.6853942,30.5867118],[-93.6920928,30.5860118],[-93.6886978,30.5911121],[-93.6929931,30.5942115],[-93.6962966,30.5933132],[-93.6998977,30.5920124],[-93.7019958,30.5903129],[-93.7038955,30.5885124],[-93.7057952,30.5883121],[-93.7118988,30.5885124],[-93.7136993,30.5858116],[-93.7143936,30.5803127],[-93.7162933,30.5785121],[-93.7193984,30.5795135],[-93.721199,30.5804119],[-93.7278976,30.573513],[-93.7263946,30.5692119],[-93.7276,30.566513],[-93.7245941,30.5625114],[-93.7241973,30.5593128],[-93.7258987,30.5570125],[-93.7284927,30.5553131],[-93.7309951,30.553112],[-93.7311935,30.5504112],[-93.7289962,30.5460128],[-93.7323989,30.5430126],[-93.7394943,30.5395126],[-93.7327957,30.5363121],[-93.7334976,30.5310115],[-93.7291946,30.5267124],[-93.7271957,30.5255126],[-93.7205963,30.5242118],[-93.7189178,30.5214767],[-93.8840332,30.523077],[-93.8791961,30.6060123],[-93.8788986,30.6090126],[-93.8769989,30.6436119],[-93.8753967,30.6672115],[-93.8737945,30.7050132],[-93.8722991,30.7341117],[-93.8714981,30.7624111],[-93.8707962,30.7792129],[-93.8694,30.8310127],[-93.8685989,30.8478126],[-93.8656997,30.9472122],[-93.8752975,30.992012],[-93.8772964,31.0002117],[-93.8796997,31.0127124],[-93.8977966,31.0957126],[-93.9110946,31.1581115],[-93.8868942,31.1594123],[-93.8597946,31.1611118],[-93.8508987,31.1615123],[-93.8252944,31.1632118],[-93.7985,31.1646118],[-93.7571945,31.1672115],[-93.7314987,31.1684112],[-93.6768951,31.171812],[-93.6455001,31.1735115],[-93.6251983,31.1748123],[-93.610794,31.1755123],[-93.6005935,31.1769123],[-93.5986938,31.174612],[-93.5883941,31.1657123],[-93.5859985,31.1661129],[-93.5835952,31.166912],[-93.5792999,31.1675128],[-93.5764999,31.1696109],[-93.5722961,31.1751117],[-93.5700988,31.1771125],[-93.5674972,31.1787128],[-93.5651931,31.1797122],[-93.5604934,31.1826114],[-93.5546951,31.1848125],[-93.5528945,31.185913],[-93.5494003,31.1865119],[-93.5438995,31.1836128],[-93.5416946,31.1834125],[-93.5379943,31.1843128],[-93.5351943,31.1854114],[-93.5332946,31.1845111],[-93.5320968,31.1821117],[-93.5317001,31.1782131],[-93.5325927,31.175312],[-93.5351943,31.1731128],[-93.5427932,31.1708126],[-93.5366973,31.1594123],[-93.539093,31.1571121],[-93.5438003,31.1564121],[-93.5476989,31.1566123],[-93.5485,31.1482124],[-93.5466003,31.1445121],[-93.544197,31.135313],[-93.537796,31.1259117],[-93.5399932,31.1143131],[-93.544197,31.1124114],[-93.5488967,31.1046123],[-93.5487976,31.1007118],[-93.5522995,31.0996112],[-93.5571975,31.0994129],[-93.5587997,31.0971126],[-93.563095,31.0968112],[-93.5634994,31.0940132],[-93.5580978,31.0903129],[-93.5550994,31.0872116],[-93.5509948,31.0881118],[-93.5513992,31.0858116],[-93.5523986,31.0818119],[-93.5513992,31.079113],[-93.5461959,31.0786113],[-93.5432968,31.0785121],[-93.5388946,31.0776119],[-93.5330963,31.0751113],[-93.5295944,31.0749111],[-93.5275955,31.0741119],[-93.5284957,31.0706119],[-93.5273971,31.0682125],[-93.5199966,31.0652122],[-93.5193939,31.0620117],[-93.5200958,31.0591125],[-93.5219955,31.0569114],[-93.5291976,31.0569114],[-93.5317001,31.0557117],[-93.5311965,31.0527114],[-93.5269927,31.0478115],[-93.5198974,31.0441112],[-93.5234985,31.0417118],[-93.5238952,31.0390129],[-93.5206985,31.0366115],[-93.5118942,31.0339126],[-93.5093994,31.0328121],[-93.5085983,31.0301113],[-93.5233993,31.0199127],[-93.5298995,31.0202121],[-93.5328979,31.0193119],[-93.5375976,31.0112113],[-93.5394973,31.0087108],[-93.5429992,31.0086116],[-93.5466995,31.0102119],[-93.5502929,31.0095119],[-93.5551986,31.0041122],[-93.5629959,31.0094127],[-93.5655975,31.012413],[-93.5721969,31.0086116],[-93.5731964,31.0047111],[-93.5747985,31.0027122],[-93.5775985,31.0000133],[-93.5746994,30.9932117],[-93.5727996,30.9915122],[-93.5683975,30.9908123],[-93.5648956,30.9896125],[-93.5652999,30.9869117],[-93.5668945,30.9806118],[-93.5679931,30.9783115],[-93.5695953,30.976511],[-93.5720977,30.9753131],[-93.5741958,30.9734115],[-93.5719985,30.9710121],[-93.5695953,30.9697132],[-93.5675964,30.9690132],[-93.5614929,30.9711132],[-93.558197,30.9701118],[-93.5548934,30.9682121],[-93.5507965,30.967411],[-93.5483932,30.9655113],[-93.5464935,30.9590129],[-93.5421981,30.9567127],[-93.539299,30.9567127],[-93.5356979,30.9578132],[-93.532196,30.9577121],[-93.5310974,30.9552116],[-93.532196,30.9519119],[-93.5323944,30.9490127],[-93.5309982,30.9446125],[-93.5289993,30.9416122],[-93.5264968,30.9396114],[-93.5275955,30.933712],[-93.5262985,30.930212],[-93.5294952,30.9276123],[-93.5314941,30.9243125],[-93.5348968,30.923912],[-93.5388946,30.9220123],[-93.542694,30.9205112],[-93.5429,30.926012],[-93.5457,30.9269123],[-93.5492935,30.923912],[-93.5522995,30.9184131],[-93.5560989,30.9153118],[-93.5584945,30.9130115],[-93.5569992,30.9108123],[-93.5536956,30.9089126],[-93.5536956,30.9025115],[-93.5492935,30.9006118],[-93.5499954,30.8977127],[-93.5519943,30.8968124],[-93.5550003,30.8965129],[-93.5585937,30.8965129],[-93.5659942,30.8948116],[-93.5680999,30.8928127],[-93.5732955,30.8871116],[-93.5734939,30.8845119],[-93.5707931,30.8758125],[-93.5674972,30.8749122],[-93.5647964,30.8755111],[-93.5637969,30.8730125],[-93.5641937,30.8694114],[-93.5606994,30.8699111],[-93.5582962,30.8692111]]]}')::geography);
```

Following is the query for `geography` and it returns `false` which is correct.

```
select ST_Intersects (st_geomFromGeoJson('{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-32.874625683,-14.310263903],[-32.874625683,73.854441883],[177.939840317,73.854441883],[177.939840317,-14.310263903],[-32.874625683,-14.310263903]]]}'), st_geomFromGeoJson('{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-93.5582962,30.8692111],[-93.5599975,30.8647117],[-93.5613937,30.8619117],[-93.5619964,30.8588123],[-93.5597,30.8556118],[-93.5576934,30.8534126],[-93.5634002,30.8473129],[-93.565895,30.8462123],[-93.5680999,30.8446121],[-93.564598,30.8421115],[-93.5589981,30.8405132],[-93.5558929,30.8377113],[-93.5537948,30.8350124],[-93.553894,30.831911],[-93.5557937,30.830511],[-93.5570983,30.8282127],[-93.5543975,30.8247127],[-93.5572967,30.8219127],[-93.5610961,30.8198127],[-93.5639953,30.8175125],[-93.5637969,30.8136119],[-93.5614929,30.8108119],[-93.5613937,30.8082122],[-93.5631942,30.8062133],[-93.5657958,30.804512],[-93.5692977,30.8030128],[-93.5735931,30.8021125],[-93.5783996,30.8020133],[-93.581398,30.803112],[-93.583496,30.8015117],[-93.5841979,30.7979125],[-93.5833969,30.794012],[-93.5815963,30.7907123],[-93.5837936,30.7882118],[-93.5868988,30.7879123],[-93.5891952,30.7871112],[-93.5884933,30.7850131],[-93.5870971,30.7831134],[-93.5839004,30.7795124],[-93.5876998,30.7778129],[-93.5914001,30.7766113],[-93.5930938,30.7710132],[-93.591896,30.7657127],[-93.5951004,30.7630119],[-93.5979995,30.7627124],[-93.6012954,30.7614116],[-93.6041946,30.7606124],[-93.6057968,30.7642116],[-93.6064987,30.7618122],[-93.606697,30.7588119],[-93.6100997,30.757513],[-93.6113967,30.7594127],[-93.6130981,30.7606124],[-93.6144943,30.7589111],[-93.6145935,30.7559127],[-93.612297,30.7538127],[-93.6092987,30.7491111],[-93.6084976,30.7470111],[-93.6099929,30.7452125],[-93.6145935,30.7444133],[-93.6177978,30.7432117],[-93.6189956,30.7409114],[-93.6167984,30.7381114],[-93.6133956,30.7369117],[-93.6114959,30.7347126],[-93.6095962,30.7306118],[-93.6114959,30.728012],[-93.6093978,30.7241115],[-93.612297,30.7221107],[-93.609497,30.7187118],[-93.6130981,30.7171115],[-93.6147003,30.7194118],[-93.6167984,30.7183113],[-93.6162948,30.7147121],[-93.6167984,30.712511],[-93.6189956,30.7098121],[-93.6210937,30.7040119],[-93.6241989,30.7009124],[-93.6237945,30.6980113],[-93.6211929,30.6959114],[-93.6226959,30.6927127],[-93.6251983,30.6899108],[-93.6271972,30.6871128],[-93.6277999,30.684412],[-93.6306991,30.6789131],[-93.6347961,30.676712],[-93.6369934,30.6745128],[-93.6388931,30.6730117],[-93.6443939,30.6735134],[-93.6464004,30.6712112],[-93.647499,30.6686115],[-93.6514968,30.6699123],[-93.6541976,30.670412],[-93.6559982,30.6687126],[-93.6582946,30.664112],[-93.6604995,30.6618118],[-93.6646957,30.6618118],[-93.6681976,30.6601123],[-93.670494,30.6572132],[-93.6702957,30.653511],[-93.6735992,30.6505126],[-93.6756973,30.6470127],[-93.6780929,30.6446132],[-93.6822967,30.6414127],[-93.6808929,30.6359119],[-93.6833953,30.6324119],[-93.6838989,30.6296119],[-93.6848983,30.6265125],[-93.6819992,30.6200122],[-93.6854934,30.6164112],[-93.6870956,30.613512],[-93.6893997,30.6118125],[-93.6877975,30.6101131],[-93.6842956,30.6089115],[-93.6828994,30.6066112],[-93.6824951,30.6042118],[-93.6791,30.5995121],[-93.6791,30.5937118],[-93.6837997,30.5931129],[-93.6850967,30.5905113],[-93.6853942,30.5867118],[-93.6920928,30.5860118],[-93.6886978,30.5911121],[-93.6929931,30.5942115],[-93.6962966,30.5933132],[-93.6998977,30.5920124],[-93.7019958,30.5903129],[-93.7038955,30.5885124],[-93.7057952,30.5883121],[-93.7118988,30.5885124],[-93.7136993,30.5858116],[-93.7143936,30.5803127],[-93.7162933,30.5785121],[-93.7193984,30.5795135],[-93.721199,30.5804119],[-93.7278976,30.573513],[-93.7263946,30.5692119],[-93.7276,30.566513],[-93.7245941,30.5625114],[-93.7241973,30.5593128],[-93.7258987,30.5570125],[-93.7284927,30.5553131],[-93.7309951,30.553112],[-93.7311935,30.5504112],[-93.7289962,30.5460128],[-93.7323989,30.5430126],[-93.7394943,30.5395126],[-93.7327957,30.5363121],[-93.7334976,30.5310115],[-93.7291946,30.5267124],[-93.7271957,30.5255126],[-93.7205963,30.5242118],[-93.7189178,30.5214767],[-93.8840332,30.523077],[-93.8791961,30.6060123],[-93.8788986,30.6090126],[-93.8769989,30.6436119],[-93.8753967,30.6672115],[-93.8737945,30.7050132],[-93.8722991,30.7341117],[-93.8714981,30.7624111],[-93.8707962,30.7792129],[-93.8694,30.8310127],[-93.8685989,30.8478126],[-93.8656997,30.9472122],[-93.8752975,30.992012],[-93.8772964,31.0002117],[-93.8796997,31.0127124],[-93.8977966,31.0957126],[-93.9110946,31.1581115],[-93.8868942,31.1594123],[-93.8597946,31.1611118],[-93.8508987,31.1615123],[-93.8252944,31.1632118],[-93.7985,31.1646118],[-93.7571945,31.1672115],[-93.7314987,31.1684112],[-93.6768951,31.171812],[-93.6455001,31.1735115],[-93.6251983,31.1748123],[-93.610794,31.1755123],[-93.6005935,31.1769123],[-93.5986938,31.174612],[-93.5883941,31.1657123],[-93.5859985,31.1661129],[-93.5835952,31.166912],[-93.5792999,31.1675128],[-93.5764999,31.1696109],[-93.5722961,31.1751117],[-93.5700988,31.1771125],[-93.5674972,31.1787128],[-93.5651931,31.1797122],[-93.5604934,31.1826114],[-93.5546951,31.1848125],[-93.5528945,31.185913],[-93.5494003,31.1865119],[-93.5438995,31.1836128],[-93.5416946,31.1834125],[-93.5379943,31.1843128],[-93.5351943,31.1854114],[-93.5332946,31.1845111],[-93.5320968,31.1821117],[-93.5317001,31.1782131],[-93.5325927,31.175312],[-93.5351943,31.1731128],[-93.5427932,31.1708126],[-93.5366973,31.1594123],[-93.539093,31.1571121],[-93.5438003,31.1564121],[-93.5476989,31.1566123],[-93.5485,31.1482124],[-93.5466003,31.1445121],[-93.544197,31.135313],[-93.537796,31.1259117],[-93.5399932,31.1143131],[-93.544197,31.1124114],[-93.5488967,31.1046123],[-93.5487976,31.1007118],[-93.5522995,31.0996112],[-93.5571975,31.0994129],[-93.5587997,31.0971126],[-93.563095,31.0968112],[-93.5634994,31.0940132],[-93.5580978,31.0903129],[-93.5550994,31.0872116],[-93.5509948,31.0881118],[-93.5513992,31.0858116],[-93.5523986,31.0818119],[-93.5513992,31.079113],[-93.5461959,31.0786113],[-93.5432968,31.0785121],[-93.5388946,31.0776119],[-93.5330963,31.0751113],[-93.5295944,31.0749111],[-93.5275955,31.0741119],[-93.5284957,31.0706119],[-93.5273971,31.0682125],[-93.5199966,31.0652122],[-93.5193939,31.0620117],[-93.5200958,31.0591125],[-93.5219955,31.0569114],[-93.5291976,31.0569114],[-93.5317001,31.0557117],[-93.5311965,31.0527114],[-93.5269927,31.0478115],[-93.5198974,31.0441112],[-93.5234985,31.0417118],[-93.5238952,31.0390129],[-93.5206985,31.0366115],[-93.5118942,31.0339126],[-93.5093994,31.0328121],[-93.5085983,31.0301113],[-93.5233993,31.0199127],[-93.5298995,31.0202121],[-93.5328979,31.0193119],[-93.5375976,31.0112113],[-93.5394973,31.0087108],[-93.5429992,31.0086116],[-93.5466995,31.0102119],[-93.5502929,31.0095119],[-93.5551986,31.0041122],[-93.5629959,31.0094127],[-93.5655975,31.012413],[-93.5721969,31.0086116],[-93.5731964,31.0047111],[-93.5747985,31.0027122],[-93.5775985,31.0000133],[-93.5746994,30.9932117],[-93.5727996,30.9915122],[-93.5683975,30.9908123],[-93.5648956,30.9896125],[-93.5652999,30.9869117],[-93.5668945,30.9806118],[-93.5679931,30.9783115],[-93.5695953,30.976511],[-93.5720977,30.9753131],[-93.5741958,30.9734115],[-93.5719985,30.9710121],[-93.5695953,30.9697132],[-93.5675964,30.9690132],[-93.5614929,30.9711132],[-93.558197,30.9701118],[-93.5548934,30.9682121],[-93.5507965,30.967411],[-93.5483932,30.9655113],[-93.5464935,30.9590129],[-93.5421981,30.9567127],[-93.539299,30.9567127],[-93.5356979,30.9578132],[-93.532196,30.9577121],[-93.5310974,30.9552116],[-93.532196,30.9519119],[-93.5323944,30.9490127],[-93.5309982,30.9446125],[-93.5289993,30.9416122],[-93.5264968,30.9396114],[-93.5275955,30.933712],[-93.5262985,30.930212],[-93.5294952,30.9276123],[-93.5314941,30.9243125],[-93.5348968,30.923912],[-93.5388946,30.9220123],[-93.542694,30.9205112],[-93.5429,30.926012],[-93.5457,30.9269123],[-93.5492935,30.923912],[-93.5522995,30.9184131],[-93.5560989,30.9153118],[-93.5584945,30.9130115],[-93.5569992,30.9108123],[-93.5536956,30.9089126],[-93.5536956,30.9025115],[-93.5492935,30.9006118],[-93.5499954,30.8977127],[-93.5519943,30.8968124],[-93.5550003,30.8965129],[-93.5585937,30.8965129],[-93.5659942,30.8948116],[-93.5680999,30.8928127],[-93.5732955,30.8871116],[-93.5734939,30.8845119],[-93.5707931,30.8758125],[-93.5674972,30.8749122],[-93.5647964,30.8755111],[-93.5637969,30.8730125],[-93.5641937,30.8694114],[-93.5606994,30.8699111],[-93.5582962,30.8692111]]]}'));
```

**Here's the first geometry:**

[image]

**Here's the second geometry:**

[image]

As you can see, they are not intersecting, for geometry params, it's always false - which is correct so was expecting `false` for geography as well but ST_intersects returns `true`.

Comment: How wide is your rectangle, in degrees? If it exceeds 180, then it may wrap the other direction to prevent antipodal operation.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Postgis, how can I measure the width here?

Comment: Surprise, on a great circle, [here is your first geometry](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=14.310263903S+32.874625683W-73.854441883N+32.874625683W-73.854441883N+177.939840317E-14.310263903S+177.939840317E-14.310263903S+32.874625683W&MS=wls&DU=km)

Comment: That's why we have geography and geometry types in GIS. Geography uses latitude, longitude on the ellipsoid while geometry uses projected coordinates to a plane. Do not use latitude and longitude as Cartesian coordinates, the result will be false.

Comment: Your JSON leaps from -32 to 177 longitude. The closest distance there crosses the dateline from the west. If you want to enclose Europe you need to add a vertex east of -3 in between, and anywhere else that the gap exceeds 180 degrees.